# Storing vector of pointers in a file and reading them again

Tags: c++, vector, std, fstream

Assume the following code:

```
// Base class
class Base {
public:
    Base(int val) : hi(val) {
    }
    virtual void PublicMethod() { /* Do something */}

private:
    int hi;
};

// Child class
class Child : public Base {
public:
    Child(int val) : Base(val) {
    }
    void PublicMethod() { /* Do something */}
};

// Vector of pointers to prevent slicing
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> list;

(...) // Fill list with mixed data of class Base and Child
```

After the list is filled with objects, I want to store the data into a file. For this I tried the following:

```
std::ofstream os("data.txt", std::ios::out);

int size1 = list.size();
os.write((const char*)&size1, sizeof(int));
for (auto it = list.begin(); it < list.end(); ++it) {
    os.write((const char*)(*it), size1 * sizeof(Base));
}
os.close();
```

However I am not sure if this is correct, and reading the data from the file also doesn't seem to work properly. I am afraid that when I'm saving the data `sizeof(Base)` also doesn't work for its child objects which might no be of the same size.

Even if this works correctly, are there better ways of storing the actual data into a file, and how can I easily read the data from the file and store them in a `shared_ptr<Base>` vector list?

Any examples would be of great help.

Comment: Quite a lot wrong there.  Dereferencing the iterator will get the shared_ptr, not the object pointed to by the pointer it wraps.  I can't even get that to build!  Even with the object you can't just cast it to a blob of bytes.  You need to look at serialisation, and overloading operator << or have your classes provide a `write()` method that takes an ofstrem that they then write their members to.

Comment: You need to provide proper serialization and deserialization for your types (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Comment: It doesn't work this way. You cannot store the pointer in a file, this is because the adresses are only valid during runtime and if you don't deallocat them. what you would have to do is serialize the data and then write them to file. This would mean you have to store the value and not the adress.

Comment: @user1158692 Sorry, my bad. I tried to shorten it but didn't test it. Thanks for the tip about serialisation and `<<` operator. @ chad I'm looking into that now, thanks. @ thebaconing That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide some form of serialization for your objects.  Here's a very trivial example (that leaves out error checking, type construction etc.)

This example shows most primitive type of serialization, but it will suffice to provide an example of what you need to do.

When you start dealing with derived classes, it becomes more tricky, as you will need some factory method to properly create the types, based on some sentinel value that you serialize.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A()
        : a_(0)
    {
    }

    A(int a, const string& n)
        : a_(a), n_(n)
    {
    }

    // a function to write objects to a stream    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const A& obj);

    // a function to read objects from a stream
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, A& obj);

private:
    int a_;
    string n_;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const A& obj)
{
    out << obj.a_ << ' ' << obj.n_;
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, A& obj)
{
    in >> obj.a_ >> obj.n_;
    return in;
}


int main()
{
    A one(1, "one");
    A also_one;

    string buffer;
    stringstream serializer;

    // write out your source object to a stream and "store it"
    // here we simply store it in a string    
    serializer << one;
    buffer = serializer.str();

    // using the "stored" value, read the stored values
    // into an (already constructed) object
    stringstream deserializer(buffer);
    serializer >> also_one;

    // verify the output is the same
    cout << one << " is the same as " << also_one << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I am dealing with derived classes. What do you mean with "factory method"? Is it possible to see to what kind of type a serialized string should be converted before actually converting it?